# How to make my surface plot appear using Axes3D?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a surface plot using Python Matplotlib. I've read the documentation in an attempt to figure out where my code was wrong or if I've left anything out, but was having trouble.

The code that I've written is

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def computeCost(X, y, theta):
    m = len(y)
    predictions = np.dot(X, theta)
    squareErros = (predictions - y) ** 2
    J = (1 / (2 * m)) * sum(squareErrors)

    return J

data = np.loadtxt("./data1.txt", delimiter=',')
X = data[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
y = data[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1)
m = len(y)
X = np.concatenate((np.ones((m, 1)), X), axis=1)

theta0_vals = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100) # size (100,)
theta1_vals = np.linspace(-1, 4, 100) # size (100,)
J_vals = np.zeros((len(theta0_vals), len(theta1_vals)))

for i in range(len(x_values)):
    for j in range(len(y_values)):
        t = np.array([theta0_vals[i], theta1_vals[j]]).reshape(-1, 1)
        J_vals[i][j] = computeCost(X, y, t) # size (100, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(theta0_vals, theta1_vals, J_vals)

plt.show()
```

When I invoke `plt.show()` I get no output. The surface plot that I'm expecting to see is similar to this:

[image]

Would anybody be kind enough to let me know where my usage of the surface plot library went wrong? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I've tried to run the demo code provided [here](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) and it works fine. Here's the code for that:

```python
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Which backend are you using for showing the plots? when you normally use plt.show() you can see the output?

Comment: @OrDinari I'm not sure which backend I'm using... I'll try and find which one it is, but yes when I use `plt.show()` it normally shows the plots that I've made.

Comment: You can use matplotlib.get_backend() for finding the backend, Some of them are not very good with showing 3d. Try changing it to qt5 by %matplotlib qt5

Comment: I just tried using `matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')` and I get the `Failed to import any qt binding.` error. Perhaps it's not a backend issue?

Comment: I've also tried copying a demo code, and that 3D plot works perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you have qt5 installed? when you use 'matplotlib.get_backend()' what is the backend your getting?

Comment: My backend is `TkAgg`. I didn't know that I needed to separately install the other backend.

Comment: TkAgg is not very good with interactive plots, such as moving 3d and animations. install qt5 and hopefully that will fix it for you.

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment regarding the demo code. Can you post your full code?

Comment: This actually is the full code that I've been attempting to run. I'll edit the demo code into my question. :)

Comment: Tried running it, theta0_vals, theta1_vals, are not defined. and J_vals is not inited. If you could post them as well.

Comment: @OrDinari Sorry that's my bad. I edited the question so that everything should be in order now. Thanks for the heads up and help.

Comment: Switching computeCost with i+j worked for me, can you add the code for computeCost as well?

Comment: Done. I'll also try switching those two.

Comment: Faking data and switching x_values, y_values with thetha0 and 1 values showed output for me. Is it not opening any output at all when you change the  J_vals[i][j] = i+j ?

Comment: Actually, rather than changing the `J_vals[i][j] = i + j`, I think I figured it out. I left out a piece of code and after some experimenting got a plot that's satisfactory. I'll edit it into my original question. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I completely agree @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and am also regretful that I didn't spend more time thoroughly researching before posting. But I initially thought it was another issue and didn't know the problem was relatively simple. I'm just glad that I figured it out and am able to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured out the issue by changing a couple of the last lines of code from

```python
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(theta0_vals, theta1_vals, J_vals)
```

to

```python
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(theta0_vals, theta1_vals, J_vals, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
```

Making this change gives me a surface plot such that:

[image]

The link that gave me reference to this was [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html).